# Trouble deploying an API using Flask, scikit-learn, and Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, flask, scikit-learn, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a very simple API, developed using Flask, that I'm trying to deploy on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk. I was able to get the API up and running without too much trouble, and it works fine when I send one request at a time. But when I send several requests at once I run into trouble.

The API has one end point whose purpose is to expose a predictive model to various other applications. It takes JSON as data sent as part of a POST request, and returns the result along with some metadata.

The model is a pre-trained scikit-learn classifier that I have serialized and stored on Amazon S3 so the web application can access it.

Here is a simplified version of the application code:

```
from __future__ import division
from datetime import datetime
import joblib
import gzip
import numpy as np
from StringIO import StringIO
from flask import Flask, request, json
from boto import connect_s3

application = Flask('myapp')


def get_model():

    s3 = connect_s3()

    b = s3.get_bucket('mybucket')
    k = b.get_key('path/to/model/trained_model.gz')
    f = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=StringIO(k.get_contents_as_string()))
    mdl = joblib.load(f)

    return mdl

mdl = get_model()

def get_input_from_json(input_json):
    return np.array(
        [[
            input_json['field1'], 
            input_json['field2'], 
            input_json['field3'],
            ...
        ]]
    )

@application.route('/predict', methods=['POST'])
def predict():

    X = get_input_from_json(request.json)

    result = mdl.predict(X)

    out = dict(
        result=result,
        eval_time=datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
    )

    return json.dumps(out)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    application.debug = True
    application.run()
```

As mentioned, I've gotten this deployed and running fine when I send individual requests, even hundreds of requests back to back. But if I send several requests at the same time, the requests fail with a 504 error.

Checking the web server logs I see some errors like `End of script output before headers: application.py`. I've seen that wsgi in its default config doesn't play well with modules that include C extensions (like scipy) and that you have to set `WSGIApplicationGroup {%Global}` in the wsgi.conf configuration file. Following http://djm.io/deploying-scipy-into-aws-elastic-beanstalk/ I modified my .ebextensions to add this line to the wsgi.conf but it hasn't helped at all. I've been Googling for other possible causes of this issue but so far have come up empty handed.

One potential problem that I can see is with the `mdl` object that lives outside of the `predict` function scope. This is the trained scikit-learn model that I have deserialized from a file stored on S3. I can't load the model inside of the `predict` function for each request; it takes too long and requests end up timing out. This is why I load the model up front and let it persist as long as the app is running. But I can imagine that I may be running into issues if this object has to be accessed by multiple executions of the `predict` function at the same time. The trouble is that I don't know how to diagnose if this is actually my issue, and if it is how I should fix it.

So is it valid to define the model at a global scope like I have done here? If not, how can I go about doing this in a more truly stateless manner? Or is there some other issue entirely?

Thanks!

Comment: **504 Gateway Time-out:** The server was acting as a gateway or proxy and did not receive a timely response from the upstream server.

Comment: I'm no expert, but I guess this is because I'm using Elastic Beanstalk. The request first has to go through the load balancer which sends the request to one of the managed instances. When none of the instances (only one in this case) doesn't respond in a timely manner the load balancer would send a 504.